# Is there some way to change windows disk size without actually increase it?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, hard-drive, disk-space-utilization, diskmanagement

What I mean is, for test purpose, Can I change the disk size showed for Windows without actually increase it.

For example, in "this computer", the real disk size is: 50gb, but I'd like to change some setting on windows to make it think that the disk is 100gb. And of course, some way to return the correct size.

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

Not for a drive backed by physical media, but you can create/attach a Dynamic VHD(X) where its capacity is larger than the size it physically consumes. Disk Management is probably the easiest way to do this.